# CPP check not on local machine

Tags: bash, cppcheck

I want to run a bash script that will run cppcheck not on my local machine.

I cloned the cppcheck repository and I want to run the cppcheck command on a certain file using bash script.

is there a an actual script in the cppcheck repository I can use (for example `./cppcheck/cppcheck.sh file.cpp` ) in order to get the results on file.cpp?

what will be the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you should not have to write a script to execute a simple command, but there are extenuating circumstances.  Where is repository?

Comment: I copied the cpp check repository into my project directory. my project is a NodeJS server and from it I call my bash script. (using SellJs lib - https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

Comment: Is the cppcheck on a shared network drive?  Will you deploy your script to the server for execution?

Comment: Yes I'm planing to deploy it. the cpp directory is inside my project root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done with the following commands:

`cd cppcheck`

then build cpp check on the machine with :

`make MATCHCOMPILER=yes CXXFLAGS=-O2`

then run the check simply by

`./cppcheck </somefile>`

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this answer. I thought the question was asking how to run `cppcheck` on a non-local machine, but this answer (by the original poster!) runs `cppcheck` on the local machine. Maybe the question really meant to ask how to compile `cppcheck` if it is not already present on the local machine?